# iOS6: willMoveToParentViewController not being called when setting views on UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, childviewcontroller

Too much code to copy here, but I have this situation:

```
myNavigationController.viewControllers = @[myViewController];
```

In iOS7 `myController willMoveToParentViewController` is called as expected.

In iOS6 it is not called.

I've bene debugging this for a day and I cannot see why iOS6 is not calling the child view controller methods. I've also checked and didMoveToParentViewController is not called either.

Has anyone encountered this and found out what causes it?